# create list when if == ok in python

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I want to add value in `list` if I the `status` is `"select"` but it overwrite the value in `list` with the last value

```py
if status == 'select':
    object_name = input("Enter a name for the tracked object:")
    Ax = x - w/2
    Ay = y - h/2
    p1 = (object_name,Ax,Ay)
    list = []
    list.append(p1)
    print(list)
    print(len(list))
```

Comment: if status == 'select':
           
            (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
            object_name = input("Enter a name for the tracked object:")
            Ax = x - w/2
            Ay = y - h/2
            p1 = (object_name,Ax,Ay)
            list = []
            list.append(p1)
    
       
            print(list)
            print(len(list))

Comment: `list = []` - this overwrites your whole list

Comment: @h4z3 technically it doesn't  "overwrite" anything, it just rebind the name `list` to a new list. If you have another reference to the original list, this one remains unaffected.

Comment: @TiaNomena unrelated (cf samthegolden's answer), but you shouldn't use a builtin type name as variable name - it shadows the builtin type and often leads to unexpected errors later in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a list each time you enter the `if` scope. Create it before so it does not override other changes.

```py
list = []

...

if status == 'select':

            object_name = input("Enter a name for the tracked object:")
            Ax = x - w/2
            Ay = y - h/2
            p1 = (object_name,Ax,Ay)
            list.append(p1)


            print(list)
            print(len(list))
```

Comment: Thank you. I have another question. If i want to compare values in Ax in firt value in list and Ax in second value in list. how do i proceed?

Comment: you may use indexes. `if Ax == list[0]` for the first value and `if Ax == list[1]` for the second.

Comment: @TiaNomena if you have another question, post it in another question. Thanks.